# For list of dicts: merge same key values, sum another diff. values, count each merge iteration +1

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, tuples

I have list of dicts(or tuples), where:

if tuples:

```
 comment_id, user_id,     comment_date, comment_time, comment_likes
('51799',   '112801710', '2015-12-07',  '00:03:21',   '0'),
('51761',   '112801710', '2015-12-06',  '19:31:46',   '3'),
('51764',   '112801710', '2015-12-06',  '19:54:19',   '0'),
('51741',   '112801710', '2015-12-06',  '14:17:34',   '2'),
('51768',   '52879933',  '2015-12-06',  '20:03:34',   '0'),
('51766',   '52879933',  '2015-12-06',  '21:33:34',   '0'),
```

or can be converted to dict like:

```
{'comm_count': 1, 'user_id': '217407103', 'likes': 0},
```

- **comment_id** - is always unique and cannot meet twice in this list,
- **user_id** - is not unique for this list, it can be there as much times as comments were left in the set of posts (naturally I wanted to use this as counter)
- **comment_date** and **comment_time** - can be ignored, needed to sel from db,
- **comment_likes** - how much likes each comment has.

The task - make one list of tuples or dictionaries where I have just one 'user_id' unique, next how much 'likes' each item has (sum) and how much times this comment, with same user id was found in list.

To clarify, this is an expected result:

```
  user_id,      comment_likes,      comments_left
('112801710',   '5',                '4'),
('52879933',    '0',                '2')
```

Somehow I made some different sets, but they does not work as expected.

**Examples of code:**

```
    for row in results:
    user_id = row[1]        # Get user id ['39411753']
    comm_id = row[0]        # Get post id ['51  575']
    comm_likes = row[4]     # Get post likes ['2']
    comm_likes = int(comm_likes)
    all_users_id_comments.append(user_id)
    if user_id not in temp_list:
        comm_count = 1
        temp_list.append(user_id)
        user_ids_dict = {'user_id':user_id,'likes':comm_likes,'comm_count':comm_count}
        result_dicts_list.append(user_ids_dict)
        if user_id in temp_list:
            for item in result_dicts_list:
                if item['user_id'] == user_id:
                    item['comm_count'] += 1
                    item['likes'] += comm_likes
```

This way can make list where user_id meet only once and make dict with same user_ids but also with values. Then it checks list with all ids and if this id meet second time - update key values. But result is not correct, I've lost comething important.

Another good way to sort:

```
merged = {}
for dict in user_comments_list_dicts:
for key,value in dict.items():
    if key not in merged:
        merged [key] = []
    merged [key].append(value)
print(merged)
```

It make one set based on user_id with list of dicts for each comment, which user left:

```
'144964044': [
          {'comm_id': '51640', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51607', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51613', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51591', 'likes': '1'},
          {'comm_id': '51592', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51317', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51319', 'likes': '0'},
          {'comm_id': '51323', 'likes': '0'}
          ],
```

But I can't call value "for 144964044" - it shows me just '144964044' but not that list. Also confuses me.

Will be great to solve this with python, but IMHO this case can be solved also on SQL db side, I don't know. Maybe I can UPDATE each row where user_id found twice or more times and sum it likes and add +1 for each in comments_count.

Also python guys gave me an advice to use: comprehensions, sets, or key\value - but I use them all - and still no result.

I want to be conscious novice, so I followed your advice about MySQL queries and found this way:

```
"""SELECT SUM(comment_likes) AS value_sum, comment_user_id, COUNT(*)
                        FROM pub_comments_weekly
                        GROUP BY comment_user_id"""
```

This will show something like:

```
((7.0, '-80849532', 3), 
(0.0, '100072457', 1), 
(4.0, '10224064', 7), 
(6.0, '10872377', 27), 
(1.0, '111612257', 5), 
(10.0, '112801710', 10), 
(0.0, '112983834', 2), 
(3.0, '11374187', 2), 
(0.0, '11558683', 1), 
(0.0, '118422944', 1), 
(0.0, '119641064', 20), 
(1.0, '119991466', 7), 
(1.0, '121321268', 1), 
(0.0, '12542463', 3))...
```

where: (likes, user_id, comments)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: please show the code that you have to create the "different sets"

Comment: Don't do this in python. databases, and you claim this is extracted from one, have things like `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` that allow counting of e.g. comments by each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

counting and summing are most efficient done in the database using count, sum functions and group by.

for some reason it is necessary that you do it in python, using a dictionary will be my choice over tuples. also I recommend using dictionary of dictionaries for the result data structure as it will make accessing it easier.

```
list = [ {'comment_id':'51799',   'user_id':'112801710', 'comment_date':'2015-12-07', 'comment_time': '00:03:21',   'comment_likes':'0'},
         {'comment_id':'51761',   'user_id':'112801710', 'comment_date':'2015-12-06',  'comment_time':'19:31:46',   'comment_likes':'3'},
         {'comment_id':'51764',   'user_id':'112801710', 'comment_date':'2015-12-06',  'comment_time':'19:54:19',   'comment_likes':'0'},
         {'comment_id':'51741',   'user_id':'112801710', 'comment_date':'2015-12-06',  'comment_time':'14:17:34',   'comment_likes':'2'},
         {'comment_id':'51768',   'user_id':'52879933',  'comment_date':'2015-12-06',  'comment_time':'20:03:34',   'comment_likes':'0'},
         {'comment_id':'51766',   'user_id':'52879933',  'comment_date':'2015-12-06',  'comment_time':'21:33:34',   'comment_likes':'0'}]


def combine(list):
    result = {}
    for item in list:
        resItem = result.get(item['user_id'], None)
        if not resItem:
            resItem =  {'comment_likes': int(item['comment_likes']), 'comments_left': 1}
        else:
            resItem['comment_likes'] += int(item['comment_likes'])
            resItem['comments_left'] +=1
        result[item['user_id']] = resItem

    print result

combine(list)
```

result:

```
{'112801710': {'comment_likes': 5, 'comments_left': 4}, '52879933': {'comment_likes': 0, 'comments_left': 2}}
```

hope this helped.

Comment: Dear Mr. user1857805 you are my hero! I still not get this logic, but many thanks to you, this works fine. Will try to understand what I do wrong.

Comment: you are welcome. please mark it answered if it meets your requirements.